# Unit Conversion in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, unit-testing, swiftui

I'm currently working on a unit conversion app, and ran into a problem that I'm still trying to figure how to solve it. The app is supposed to convert one unit to a different unit, and supposed to convert and display new value in the text view every time a unit is converted to a different unit.(meters to kilometers, miles to yards, etc.). I created a computed property called result which handles the conversion, but when I run the code in the simulator and toggle between the units, no changes are displayed to show the units converted successfully. I tried using a guard statement before the calculations since I figured Value is 0 after converting inputNumber to an integer, but that doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure where I went wrong but any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I have attached the code and simulator below.
Thanks.

PS. I have learned how to and can build this app using the measurement functionality provided by Apple, I'm trying to learn how to build it in a different way by basically using math calculations only.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var inputNumber = ""
    @State private var inputUnitValue = 2
    @State private var outputUnitValue = 2
    @State private var outputValue = ""
    
    let inputUnits = ["Feet", "Meters", "Kilometers", "Yard", "Miles"]
    let outputUnits = ["Feet", "Meters", "Kilometers", "Yard", "Miles"]
    
    var result: Double {
        
        var outputType = ""
        var inputType = ""
        
        let value = Double(inputNumber) ?? 0
        
        var output = Double(outputValue) ?? 0
        var input = Double(inputNumber) ?? 0
        
        
        guard value > 0 else {
            return 0
        }
        //Converts input value to input unit
        switch inputUnits[inputUnitValue] {
        case "meters":
            input = value * 3.28
        case "kilometers":
            input = value * 3280.84
        case "yards":
            input = value * 3
        case "miles":
            input = value * 5280
        case "feet":
            input = value * 1
        default:
            input = value * 3.28
        }
        
        //Converts input unit to output unit
        switch outputUnits[outputUnitValue] {
        case "meters":
            output = value / 3.28
        case "kilometers":
            output = value / 3280.84
        case "yards":
            output = value / 3
        case "miles":
            output = value / 5280
        case "feet":
            output = value / 1
        default:
            output = value / 3.28
        }
        
        return output
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    TextField("Value", text: $inputNumber)
                        .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    
                }
                Section(header: Text("Input Units")) {
                    Picker("Input Units", selection: $inputUnitValue) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< inputUnits.count) {
                            Text("\(self.inputUnits[$0])")
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                }
                Section(header: Text("Output Units")) {
                    Picker("Input Units", selection: $outputUnitValue) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< outputUnits.count) {
                            Text("\(self.outputUnits[$0])")
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                }
                Section (header: Text("output")){
                    Text("\(result, specifier: "%.2f")")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Unit Conversion")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image: Unit conversion app]

Comment: I would suggest using an `enum` for your different unit types. See https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`switch` is case sensitive. Your `inputUnits` and `outputUnits` are capitalized...

```
let inputUnits = ["Feet", "Meters", "Kilometers", "Yard", "Miles"]
```

... while your switch conditions are lowercased.

```
switch inputUnits[inputUnitValue] {
case "meters": /// lowercased
    ...
}
```

So, your `switch` statement always falls through to the `default`.

To fix, just add `.lowercased()`:

```
switch inputUnits[inputUnitValue].lowercased() {
```

```
switch outputUnits[outputUnitValue].lowercased() {
```

---

One more thing: I assume the purpose of your `switch`es are to:

1. Convert `value` to a standard feet unit
2. Convert that feet to the output unit

In this case, inside the second `switch`, you need to perform calculations using your `input` variable (which is the input converted to feet) - **not `value`**.

To make things less confusing, I've renamed `input` to `inputAsFeet`.

```
var result: Double {
    
    let value = Double(inputNumber) ?? 0
    
    var inputAsFeet = Double(0)
    var output = Double(0)
    
    guard value > 0 else {
        return 0
    }
    
    switch inputUnits[inputUnitValue].lowercased() {
    case "meters":
        inputAsFeet = value * 3.28
    case "kilometers":
        inputAsFeet = value * 3280.84
    case "yards":
        inputAsFeet = value * 3
    case "miles":
        inputAsFeet = value * 5280
    case "feet":
        inputAsFeet = value * 1
    default:
        inputAsFeet = value * 3.28
    }

    switch outputUnits[outputUnitValue].lowercased() {
    case "meters":
        output = inputAsFeet / 3.28
    case "kilometers":
        output = inputAsFeet / 3280.84
    case "yards":
        output = inputAsFeet / 3
    case "miles":
        output = inputAsFeet / 5280
    case "feet":
        output = inputAsFeet / 1
    default:
        output = inputAsFeet / 3.28
    }
    
    return output
}
```

Result:

[image: Result is updated when segmented control changes]

Comment: why not simply use the same string instead of lowercasing it? Btw there is a Measurement type exactly for this purpose which would avoid hardcoding the values

Comment: @LeoDabus yeah I agree. As [@JoakimDanielson said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67589940/unit-conversion-in-swiftui#comment119469041_67589940) an enum would probably be even better. But anyway OP said they didn't want to use Measurement - "using math calculations only"

Comment: @aheze, I appreciate your help with this, I didn't even realize I had my input units capitalized, The app works perfectly now after the revisions, such a small change but huge difference!! Thanks.

Comment: @LeoDabus, I have learned using the measurement type, which actually I prefer using than hardcoding, I just wanted to learn a different way of approaching it. I appreciate your help.